# model selection with glmnet

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, glmnet, categorical-encoding

I am trying to fit a multinomial logit model using glmnet. I have a few questions:

1. How is the baseline category specified?
2. Looking at the model coefficients using coef.glmnet, I'm thinking that many are given by a   dot. I assume this means the coefficient was set to zero by LASSO, so the variable was dropped. However, I'm finding that variables are dropped this way even when lambda=0, so there is no regularizing term. Can someone explain what's going on here?
3. Sometimes I find that a variable is dropped in some but not all of the logits. How should this be interpreted?

Here is a working example:

```
library(glmnet)
data(iris)
X <- model.matrix(Species ~., data=iris)
y <- iris$Species
fit <- glmnet (X, y, family="multinomial")
coef(fit, s=0)
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per post ( you can link between them for common background)

Answer (score 2):

Q1:  `glmnet` do not use (or need) a baseline category. The penalization takes care of the linear dependence, no matrix is inverted during the fitting! Furthermore, it would **be an error** to use a baseline category, because different choices would lead to fitted models giving different predictions. See discussion in [Dropping one of the columns when using one-hot encoding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding/329281#329281)

Q2: Not sure about this, probably has to do with details about the algorithm (which is iterative, not exact). Leaving that one to others.

Q3: The usual lasso do not know about different dummys belonging to the same categorical variable, so it might choose to set different variables to zero. To avoid that, use the *group lasso*.  See  [Why use group lasso instead of lasso?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214325/why-use-group-lasso-instead-of-lasso)